# I have the famous problem when installing MAVEN something like Fatal error "invalid target release"

Tags: maven, pom.xml

After rerunng with -X it says 'No goals have been specified for this build'

I have already set all the envirenment variables as they should
JAVA_HOME==>to the jdk1.8.0 folder and the M2_HOME==>C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3

There is my pom.xml file ::>

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please no images of POM files. Copy the text.

Comment: You are describing at least two different things. The headline says something about `invalid target release` where as the text says ´No gaols have been ...` ? And please post in text and not images .... full pom file....

Answer (score 0):

You're using Java 8, so you can't build a Java 11 application. Either installer Java 11 (or newer) and point your `JAVA_HOME` to it, or modify the `java.version` property to `1.8` (assuming your code doesn't rely on new features from Java 11).

Comment: Mureinik you got it man thank you so much !! I re-downloaded the project with java 8 and evrything went smoothly